# ExtJS 5.1.2 : Getting 'Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null' in reconfigure function

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

Ever since I upgraded from ExtJS 5.1.1 to ExtJS 5.1.2, I am getting 'Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null' for the statement:

```
this.reconfigure(tfStore, tfColumns);
```

The functionality was working fine in the older version.

Here is my code:

```
loadTopicsView: function(record, cellIndex) {
    var tfStore = Ext.create("rspTraining.store.trainingItems.TopicFrequencyValues",{ clientId: record.get('client_id')});
    var trainingParams = {
        clientId: record.get('client_id')
    };  
    tfStore .load({
        params : trainingParams
    });
    this.reconfigure(tfStore, topicColumns);
},
```

The loadTopicView is called in a cell click listener of a grid:

```
listeners: {
    cellclick: function(grid, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex) {
        if (cellIndex == 3 && record.get('client_id')) {
            this.loadTopicsView(record, cellIndex);
        }
        if (cellIndex == 0 && record.get('topics')) {
            this.loadRetailProView(record, cellIndex);
        }
    }
},
```

The 'topicColumns' is a column array:

```
var topicColumns = [{
    text: "Topics",
    dataIndex: "topics",
    flex: 7,
    renderer: function(val, meta, record) {
        meta.tdCls = "percent-projects-cell";
        return val;
    }
}, {
    text: "# of Re-trainings",
    dataIndex: "re-trainings",
    flex: 1
}, {
    text: "% of Re-trainings",
    dataIndex: "re-trainings-percentage",
    flex: 1,
    renderer: function(val, meta, record){
        val = Ext.util.Format.round(val,2) + '%';
        return val;
    }       
}];
```

Is there any possible solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Issue is fixed. Used 'Ext.getStore()' instead of 'Ext.create()'.